# HT Access not working

Tags: html, .htaccess

I've followed several online guides to redirect "londonosophy.com" to the "www.london..."  version, however it doesn't seem to be redirecting. Being concerned about duplicating content, can anyone suggest how to improve the htaccess file I have as below please?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^londonosophy\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.londonosophy.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://([ -a-z0-9]  \.)?londonosophy\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ - [F,NC,L]

#cache html and htm files for one day
<FilesMatch ".(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=43200"
</FilesMatch>

#cache css, javascript and text files for one week
<FilesMatch ".(js|css|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
</FilesMatch>

#cache flash and images for one month
<FilesMatch ".(flv|swf|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>

#disable cache for script files
<FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
Header unset Cache-Control
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: is .htaccess enabled in the virtual host file?

Comment: I am using GoDaddy webhosting, which I presumed enabled by default, but please correct me if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to the `"londonosophy.com" to the "www.london..."` use bellow code inside .htaccess file

```
# This allows you to redirect your entire website to any other domain
Redirect 301 / http://www.london...
```

As you comment said "I just want to add "www" in front of each of my URLs as a redirect".So use bellow code will solve the problem

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I just want to add "www" in front of each of my URLs as a redirect, will this solve this issue?